# Apache: Proxy 2 URLS to different port on same domain

Tags: apache, jenkins, solr, routes

I have jenkins and solr running on machine. (8080, 8081 ports)

I would like a configuration to do this proxy

www.example.com/jenkins => localhost:8080/jenkins

AND

www.example.com/solr => localhost:8081/solr

It is not working. Only the jenkins works. Solr does not.

```
ProxyPass         /solr  http://localhost:8081/solr nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /solr  http://localhost:8081/solr
```

Result of `apachectl -S`

```
VirtualHost configuration:

*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server example.com/jenkins (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/jenkins.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost example.com/jenkins (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/jenkins.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost example.com/solr (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/solr.conf:1)
.
```

solr.conf file

```
<Virtualhost *:80> 
ServerName example.com/solr 
DocumentRoot /var/www/solr/public_html 
ProxyRequests Off 
ProxyPreserveHost On 
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode 

<Proxy http://localhost:8081/*>
 Order deny,allow Allow from all 
</Proxy> 

ProxyPass /solr http://localhost:8081/solr nocanon 
ProxyPassReverse /solr http://localhost:8081/solr 

</Virtualhost>
```

Comment: put them in the same `conf` file.

Comment: In the same virtualhost block? or different?
.
I merged the conf files as it is. And it does not work.
First virthostblock with jenkins proxy and servername,
Second virtualhostblock with solr proxy and servername

Comment: If both are being served in the same `servername` value, then put them in the same VHost config

Comment: It worked with same servername. I had them different.